# Swift NSTableview Drag Selects Multiple Rows Instead of Dragging Out of Table

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I'm trying to drag files from an NSTableView and drop them on the Finder.  When I try to drag a row, nothing happens other than I wind up selecting multiple rows if I drag down the table.  My init code for the table is:

```
filesList.delegate = self
filesList.dataSource = self
filesList.doubleAction = #selector(doubleClick)
filesList.registerForDraggedTypes([.fileURL])
let descriptorName = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
let descriptorSize = NSSortDescriptor(key: "size", ascending: true)
let descriptorAttr = NSSortDescriptor(key: "attr", ascending: true)
filesList.tableColumns[0].sortDescriptorPrototype = descriptorName
filesList.tableColumns[1].sortDescriptorPrototype = descriptorSize
filesList.tableColumns[2].sortDescriptorPrototype = descriptorAttr
filesList.setDraggingSourceOperationMask([.copy], forLocal: false)
```

Later on, I have this code which doesn't do much right now. I'm hoping this will give me the path to the folder that was dropped on.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet, to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
    guard let board = pboard.propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "NSFilesPromisePboardType ")) as? NSArray,
        let path = board[0] as? String
        else { return false }
    print(path)
    return true
}
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Willeke's tip below, I was able to get it to almost work.  Below is my updated code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,pasteboardWriterForRow row: Int)-> NSPasteboardWriting?
{
    var filePaths = [String]()
    let item = NSPasteboardItem()
    let folderPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())

    let toPath = folderPath.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")
    for (_, index) in filesList.selectedRowIndexes.enumerated() {
        var fileName = files[index].name
        if self.dirPath != "" {
            fileName = "\(self.dirPath)/\(fileName)"
        }
        let command="\"\(getImgTool())\" get \(self.format) \"\(self.path)\" \"\(fileName)\" \"\(toPath)\(fileName)\""
        //                    let command = "cd ~; \(self.getImgTool()) put \(self.format) \(self.path) \(fileName) \(filePath)"

        let _ = shell(command)
        filePaths.append("\(toPath)\(fileName)")
    }

    item.setPropertyList(filePaths, forType: .fileURL)

    return item
}
```

The problem I'm having now is that the Finder won't accept the drop.  Xcode is reporting "Sandbox extension data required immediately for flavor public.file-url, but failed to obtain."  So, I changed .fileURL to .URL and the Finder accepts it but the file isn't written/copied.  What am I missing?

Comment: Tip: use `tableView(_:pasteboardWriterForRow:)` instead of `tableView(_:writeRowsWith:to:)` and return the url.

Comment: More tips: return the `URL` for the item at row `row` instead of a list of all selected rows. Use `URL` methods instead of path strings to construct the `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that you also need to set the dragging mask so that it allows drags to *other* apps, like this:

```
tableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask (.every, false)
```

Or something along that line.